# How can I prevent str_replace from replacing twice in a row?

Tags: php, str-replace

I wasn't sure how to word this question properly, apologies.

I'm trying to create clean virtual directories from names in a database. These names could be `foo bar`, `foo/bar`, `foo / bar`, `foo: bar` and so on.

I'm trying to replace `spaces`, `:`, `/` with `-` to clean up the URLs so I have:

```
$search_array = array(" ","-", ":", "/");
$clean_url = str_replace($search_array, "-", $name);
```

In the case of `foo bar`, this changes it to `foo-bar` which is my desired result, but when it comes to something like `foo : bar` it changes to `foo---bar`

Is there some way I can get str_replace to only replace once if multiple results are found?

I thought about placing things such as `[space]:[space]` in the search array but I have about 600,000 names an am not sure of the amount of combinations there are.

Comment: Time to look into regexp.

Comment: Why dont you try something which is already there, http://cubiq.org/the-perfect-php-clean-url-generator

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`str_replace` won't do what you want here. You need to use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) have a look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).